# Laptop CPU Frequency Dropping

Tags: laptop, cpu

I am looking for some help on what is going on with my laptop. Whenever I try to play a game on this machine the CPU will not reach its max frequency (2.5 GHz non-turbo, 3.6 GHz turbo) and instead sit at 1.5 GHz at 100% utilization. As a test for thermal issues I ran prime95 will providing chilled air for intake. This resulted in a max temp of 40 C and still no improvement. Please help...I want to use my full CPU capacity.

System:
Asus X54H-BD1BH
CPU: 2860QM
MOBO: K54L

Comment: Even plugged in it has the same issue

Comment: Hwmonitor shows 31% wear if that's what your looking for...so not the best

Comment: But the laptop works normally on battery power? (Other than this frequency issue?)

Comment: Yes, it does. Works fine normally

Comment: I can't find any evidence that the X54H-BD1BH supports the 2860QM. It seems to be supported pretty much only with a Pentium B950. Are you sure the laptop supports the CPU? I think you have a CPU in a motherboard that doesn't support it.

Comment: I added a custom BIOS patch for the 2860qm CPU from another Asus laptop.

Comment: Originally I don't think it did

Comment: I honestly don't see how that motherboard can supply enough power for the 2860QM. It seems the 2860QM needs about 40% more power than the VRM on that board can supply.

Comment: I'm guessing that's not something that could be adjusted... right?

Comment: It's something you should have checked before you connected the two things together! Do you have any reason to think that motherboard can power that CPU? The specs don't even seem to be close.

Comment: How did you find that...by the TDP?

Comment: That was the starting point, yes.

Comment: Honestly, it can and will hold 2.4 - 2.5 ish GHz in certain applications. Just prime and some games will not move past 1.6 GHz...any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like a power or cooling limitation. When you say the max temp was 40C, was that the die temperature, core temperature, or some other temperature? (Do you know?)

Comment: I tried testing before with prime95 and kept the CPU at 40 C but thermals do need to be improved. Not sure that thermals alone cause this issue because that test still stayed at 1.6 GHz...could just be some strange glitch with prime

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a fresh install of windows on a laptop I own. The solution so far has been using throttlestop to force the CPU multiplier to max. This requires speedstepping or EIST to be enabled, I believe the windows power profile should be set to "high performance", and you can retain speedstepping gains by ticking off the "Power Saver" and "SLFM" boxes.

More information may be found [In this nootbookreview thread](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/the-throttlestop-guide.531329/) and you can download throttlestop [from this techpowerup webpage](https://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/2288/throttlestop-6-00)

If I happen to figure anything more out, I'll be sure to share. My current "solution" however, is probably going to be to reinstall from a different disc. Presently I'm suspicious that it may be an interaction between various Windows updates, or drivers on the computer. I realize this isn't a very good solution in the long term, as installs are arduous and not an option for many people.

If I knew exactly what throttlestop was doing and how to do it myself, I'd set it as a startup/login script and settle for that.

Comment: In my case the machine in question is a Lenovo X61t with a L7700 1.8Ghz CPU that in a separate installation of Windows 7 SP1, performed at a full 200x9 CPU multiplier resulting in 1.8Ghz. Following an install of Windows 7 that was then updated to SP1 discretely, performance was observed to be capped at 200x6 CPU multiplier, resulting in 1.2Ghz. This was using the 90W power adapter the machine came with, though a 65W adapter was also tested.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Throttlestop has been patchy for me at best but I'm assuming that's due to my older hardware...perhaps.

Comment: I will try this, however